# How to step through a git repository?

Tags: git, branch

I am trying to understand a project, it helps to look at its evolution by using gitk. What I do is checkout the first commit, understand code, run tests, go to next commit and repeat. My  current workflow is to checkout the commit through its hash

```
git checkout 79cd6
```

But what I would like is another branch where I can perform my own changes, and allows me to merge commits from the master branch, but without the need to find the commit hash. Idealized workflow:

```
git checkout -b <newbranch> <first commit id of master>
git <command to move head of current branch to next commit of master>
```

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but I wanted to do the same thing and found an answer so I figured I'd share.

```
for commit in $(git rev-list master --reverse)
do
    git checkout $commit
    read
done
```

do this in one window. It will start with your initial commit, and advance once each time you hit enter. Then do your testing etc. in a different shell.
It'll work perfectly with a linear history, but I'm not quite sure how it will handle merges and such. I'm sure it'll be reasonable, but your mileage might vary a bit.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! You can also use `git rev-list master ^[hash of first commit to checkout]^ --reverse` if you don't want to checkout the entire history.

Comment: I'd also add `git checkout master` to the end so you end up back on the correct branch.

Comment: Here's my resulting bash file: https://gist.github.com/cletusw/a2381514ecbd0c2c48dc

Answer (score 3):

Save this as `~/bin/git-next` or somewhere else in your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
git co $(git rev-list --children --all | awk "/^$(git rev-parse @\{0})/ { print \$2; }")
```

This will check out the first child of the current revision.

It will be *very* slow on a big repo but it will do the job.

You can modify this to handle your branching as needed.

Comment: If the speed is a problem, you could store the output of `git rev-list <branch>`, and just find the line with your current HEAD on it and check out the line before.

Comment: Thanks! I made it an alias with a slightly different syntax: `alias gitnext='git checkout $(git rev-list --children --all | grep "$(git rev-parse @{0}) " | awk "{print \$2}")'`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little shell script. One script would run `git log --pretty=oneline | awk '{print $1;}'`. The second script (call it `step` or something) would use `head`, `tail`, `wc -l`. Then  read the last line of the file with `tail`, find out how many lines are in the file, and remove the last line from the file. Ugly, sure, but it'd do the job. :) (If you wanted to be a little less ugly, it could use `truncate(1)` to just chop off the last line of the file, rather than always making new temporary files.)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted an easy way to step through commits in a branch for code review/demo.  This is the little  script I came up with to automate it.  Drop the following in a file, say, `git_step` and run it like so: `git_step d17dacce8b13b2ad454003da7cbd670a06c41437`

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_REV=${BASE_REV:-$1};
current_branch=$(git branch | grep '^*' | awk '{print $2}');

for rev in $(git rev-list ${BASE_REV}..HEAD | tail -r); do
    git checkout $rev;
    LESS='RSX' git show -p $rev;
done;

git checkout ${current_branch};
```

Also available as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/rca/db862e857ba39e7d169b).